# How can I generate this pattern?

Tags: graph-theory, fractals

I've been working on a problem (full problem at the bottom) and as a result I've generated some binary matrices with a peculiar pattern.  Here is the pattern for $n=29$ (the largest $n$ before my image editor craps out).  A black pixel represents a $1$ and a white pizel represents a $0$.

[image: n = 29]

These matrices are generated with the following method.

Given $n$ as input:

First we generate all the collection, $C$, of lists consisting of $2$ and $3$ that sum to $n$ (in dictionary order).
For example if $n$ is $8$ then our collection is $[[2,2,2,2],[2,3,3],[3,2,3],[3,3,2]]$.

Or matrix $M(n)$ is then defined as

$$
M(n)_{i,j} = \begin{cases}0 & \exists x,y\in\mathbb{N}: \sum(\mathrm{take}(x)(C_i)) = \sum(\mathrm{take}(y)(C_j))\\1 & \mathrm{otherwise}\end{cases}
$$

Here is some Haskell code that generates these matrices:

```
rowsOf (-1) = [[]]
rowsOf 0 = [[]] : rowsOf (-1)
rowsOf 1 = [] : rowsOf 0
rowsOf n
  | l <- rowsOf $ n-1 = ((map (3:) $ l!!2) ++ (map (2:) $ l!!1)) : l

partialSums = init.tail.scanl(+)0

adjacencyMatrix n = do
  a <- rows
  pure $ do
    b <- rows
    pure $ if all (`notElem` partialSums a) $ partialSums b
             then 1
             else 0
  where
    rows = head $ rowsOf n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZAxT8MwEIV3/4pXicFWlCopC6rakbFiYKwqek1cxXBxIsdVQeK/h0toqoAn@313752vou7DMvd9aK7dyxk6zQ222O8PB3WTstsba8yKJpoPdMayCXgFfIOxSSf0AJ8O5VrX1EI/ro1IvFisDJIEv@JqEnNjxJSVailER/x6qTvpdd7FZSTHy64gzzoxmVJUvlNhffG1oxjcJ7wUlo3k05Qu9/YSrFiPOnCakTtzZxAz9NE38ZltfcQ8nIbJ5sJp7L2fWFmP/K9mubOyEuBa2WBHNoTKfJWlUvymZfU1Ob@VFeze0Abno7D/33rqfwA)

From here my question is is this a known pattern?  It is rather reminiscent of the Serpinski gasket.  Is there a faster way to generate these matrices other than the brute force method shown above?

---

### Original Problem

I saw [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/180714/unique-brick-tilings-within-a-rectangle) on code-golf (based on a now deleted SO question) a little while ago and I have been working on a solution to it using an transformation matrix approach.

The question is as follows:

> Given a width $M$ and a height $N$, write a program that outputs how many
>   unique ways an $M\times N$ rectangle can be filled by $2\times 1$ and $3\times 1$ tiles given these constraints.
>
> 1. All tiles stay within their row (ie they are all horizontal).
> 2. Between every two adjacent rows tiles should not be aligned, except on the two ends.

In this problem the each row and column represents a way to fill a single size $M$ row. And an element indicates whether those two rows can be places next to each other in the final project without violating rule 2.  If I had such a matrix I could use it as a transition matrix and find the desired result very quickly with matrix composition.

Comment: It looks like the attractor of a self-affine iterated function system to me.  However, I don't read Haskell, and don't really understand what you are doing, so about the best I can do is **shrug**.  That being said, it is not a Seirpinski gasket---the object you have drawn appears to be simply connected, while the gasket is not.